# Spring JMS & ActiveMQ Artemis: manage timeout for synchronous messages

Tags: java, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a huge application using JMS to communicate. Unfortunately, all the messages are synchronous for now and we use the method `JmsTemplate#sendAndReceive`.

All right, it works ! But....

If we have a timeout, the producer closes the temporary queue (defined to receive the response), as expected. But when the listener ends the treatment, it will recreate the temporary queue to send the response. This queue is temporary (with no consumer), but the address is not flagged as temporary as well.

The result is that we have multiple addresses and queues waiting a consumer to treat the response and it will never happen.

How to prevent the re-creation of the temporary queue if the producer (of the original message) closed it before, and doesn't wait anymore?

Edit: I'm using Artemis 2.29.0, but I have the the same behavior with the last version 2.31.0

Comment: What do you mean by, "when the listener ends the treatment"?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: When the listener sends the response (so after the timeout of the original producer). I'm using the version 2.29.0, but I tried the last one (2.31.0) and I have the same behavior

Comment: An explanation of what I see in the code of Spring & artemis-jms-client. When Spring tries to send the response, it calls ActiveMQSession#createProducer that will create a durable address and the temporary queue through the method ActiveMQSession#checkDestination.  

As the address is not temporary, I can't set specific configuration to delete temporary queues if there's no consumer on it.  

The only solution I see here is to forbidden the automatic creations of queues. It will throws an InvalidDestinationException, but I don't have the temporary queue created after the timeout

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. For the time being you can work-around the issue by configuring automatic address deletion via the `auto-delete-addresses` address-setting. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html#address-settings) for more details on that setting and other related settings.

Answer (score 0):

In many use cases of synchronous communication pattern, the response of the service provider is of no value anymore, after the requester stops waiting for it. And I believe you describe such a use case. Then it makes sense to set a time to live for the request message:

```
JMSTemplate.setTimeToLive(long timeToLiveInMs)
```

Set it to a value corresponding to your timeout. If there is a delay in the service provider consuming the request, the message will expire approximately at the time you stop waiting for the response, thus the service provider won’t be bothered with processing this request anymore and hence won’t send a redundant response. Unless you have not specified an expiry address in your address setting, the expired messages are deleted.

This might not eliminate every single case of redundant response, for example, when the response is created in time, but there is a delay in transmitting it to your application, or because your application goes down during your timeout interval. Thus, the service provider should propagate a time to live value of the request message to the response message. And I agree with your comment, the service provider should not be allowed to re-create the response queue. With time to live, the occurrence of these attempts will happen less often.

Comment: The problem is the address. It's not a temporary address (unlike the address created by the original producer), so I can't set a specific configuration through the address settings.

Set a time to live can be a good idea, but it only will delete the message  (and maybe the temporary queue, I will test it). But the address, not temporary, can stay without any queue in it. It's what I can see when I shutdown my application : the queue is destroyed but not the address.